# Hide certain post types from editors

Tags: functions, admin-menu, add-editor-style

I'm trying to hide a series of posts from my editors in the admin panel based on either custom post type or category (whichever is easiest).

I tried adding a function such as:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if($current_user->user_login = 'test2') {
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=post', 'edit.php?post_format=image&amp;post_type=post' );
        }
}
```

(In this snippet, I'm hiding it from one specific account) but it doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'series of posts'? What are you trying to hide?

Comment: @StephenHarris Basically, I'd like to hide all posts filed under a certain category so that an editor can't edit it. Ex.: Editors won't be able to see anything filed under "Dogs" category

Comment: OK, your snippet appears to be attempting to remove a nonexistent admin submenu, In WordPress if a user can only edit a subset of posts they can still see the others. If that's sufficient I'd recommend looking into meta capability mapping: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap or a hook in `current_user_can`. Will try to furnish you with details unless you/someone posts an answer in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Here a little function which takes care to hide (In admin) Custom Post Types.

```
function remove_from_admin_menu(){
    // Check capability (admin)
    if( current_user_can( 'edit_dashboard' )){
        //Do nothing
    } elseif ( current_user_can( 'moderate_comments' ) ) { // editor capability
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=cpt01' ); // add here your cpt name
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=cpt02' );             
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=cpt03' );
        // for submenu pages
        remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=testimonials-widget', 'testimonialswidget_settings' ); 

    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_from_admin_menu');
```

FYI:
About roles/capabilities see [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table).
Remove [menu page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page). (Codex)
Remove [sub-menu page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page).(Codex) 
Credits to [michael-cannon](https://gist.github.com/michael-cannon/6701832) for his sub-menu cpt sample.(Github)

To do the same kind of trick for categories you could take a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173369/15605) because it is unclear to me if that is what you realy want to do that way. If yes, then the credits should go to him and not to me :)